# Displaying Validation Error Messages in Struts2

Tags: java, web, struts2, struts

I am new to Struts 2, have worked in Struts 1 earlier.

How can we bind a error message with a UI component (e.g. a Text box) ? I don't want the error message to be a global one.

For achieving the same in Struts 1:

In the form validate method, I used this:

```
ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();       
if(userName != null && userName.length() <= 0)
    errors.add("userName",new ActionError("error.userName.required"));
```

and in the UI, for displaying the message:

```
<html:messages id="userName" property="userName">
    <bean:write name="userName"/>
</html:messages>
```

In Struts 2, If I extend the Action  class with `ActionSupport` and use this:

```
addActionError(getText("Please enter UserId"));
```

Then it seems to be a global message which can be displayed in the UI using:

```
<s:actionerror />
```

Hence not sure how to achieve the same functionality in Struts 2. Kindly let me know on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The `<s:fieldError>` tag](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/fielderror.html) would be the closest equivalent:

```
<s:fielderror fieldName="userName" />
```

On the Java side you'd use `ValidationAware.addFieldError` to add field-specific messages:

```
public class AnyAction extends ActionSupport {
    public void validate() {
        addFieldError("userName", "User ID is required");
    }
}
```

That said, for the low-level validations, I'd stick to the default XML-based mechanism when possible, since it does a lot of this work for you, and makes working with I18N/properties a little easier.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I us `addFieldError` in the java file and don't use any `<s:fieldError ...>` in the jsp file, then also the error message is getting displayed. And if I use the `<s:fieldError ...>` in the jsp along with the `addFieldError` in the java file, then some of the error messages are getting repeated. Why this sort of behavior? Also the UI is getting scrapped while displaying the messages :(

Comment: @user182944 Because you haven't read much of the S2 docs. The default "xhtml" theme creates table rows/cells around form labels and fields, and displays field errors by default.

Comment: Please provide the exact link for this "xhtml" theme, I will go through it. I am new and not sure what is achievable hence facing a lot of problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user182944 Off the [guides](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/guides.html) page, start on the [themes and templates](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/themes-and-templates.html), then the ["xhtml theme"](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/xhtml-theme.html). "Viewing source" would lead to the conclusion that the S2 UI tags generated additional HTML.